# External microphone input on iphone 7

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, recording

Does anyone know how to import a microphone mono audio into iphone 7? Can I use a bluetooth transmitter to carry the microphone audio? Can an APP to pick up the microphone audio via bluetooth? like Apple watch. Thanks.

Comment: Have you already got an external microphone? Have you tried connecting it to the Lightning port via the Lightning to  3.5mm headphone adaptor? If so, what happens?

Comment: I used a condenser microphone to plug into the 3.5mm headphone jack on my iphone6 but nothing happened. No sound input. I'm planning to buy an new iphone7 now. So just wondering if I can use Bluetooth input like Apple Watch.

Comment: Well, if all you want to know is whether you can use a bluetooth microphone then the answer is yes. I can't comment on your exact scenario (i.e. what apps etc you use), but assuming you're using software that will use the Bluetooth microphone (i.e. allow you to select the audio source) you will be fine.